# Django validation: Use field label insted of field name in error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to use **label name** instead of **field name** in `django` form validation.

For example in a invalid form one might get errors like these:

```
"passenger_email":["This field is required."]
```

How can I get

```
"Passenger email":["This field is required."]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write custom exception handler http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    view = context['view']
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    fields = view.get_serialzer().get_fields()
    details = {}
    for k, v in response.data['detail'].items():
        try:
            field = fields[k]
            label = getattr(field, 'label', '')
            if label:
                detail[label] = v
            else:
                detail[k] = v
        except KeyError:
            detail[k] = v

    response.data['detail'] = detail
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you get this from `form.errors`

So i recommend you not overriding `form.errors` but making copy of it, because you can break template error rendering.

```
another_errors = {form.fields[field].label: error for field, error in form.errors.items()}
```

I believe that will do.